# Common (platform independent) solution to send print jobs to a computer in any foreign network (e.g. via email)?

Tags: windows, networking, email, printing, services

Imagine a common "private" network with a printer which I technically cannot (and must not!) reach because I'm in a different network and I want to be able to print a file (pdf) on this printer.
Example: I want to print a file at home of a friend of mine. Port forwarding etc. is not an option but I can send data through common "internet media channels" like email or chat.

Is there a way e.g. via a server running on this friends computer (running windows XP..8) to print files via mail or chat?

I think it would not very difficult to write a small python program which listens on an email account for incoming "print jobs" via file attachments an prints them e.g. via ghostscript or acrobat reader.

Would be nice to have a platform independent solution but this service has to be available at least on Windows.

Note: Automatic email printing from Outlook is not an option. I have to be able to just start the "printer computer" without logging in to run the described service.

Addon: As commented, services like Google Cloud Print would be exactly the solution I'm looking for but you would give your (or your company's) IP to the cloud provider which is sub-optimal for me.

Comment: maybe google cloud print?

Comment: yes that's an option. at least if you are not paranoid.. I'll give it a try but I'd prefer a solution which would not give every document I print away to google :)

Answer (score 0):

Not endorsing the product, but Namtuk's [Automatic Email Manager](http://www.namtuk.com/auto_email_manager.aspx) might be what you're looking for. Runs as a Windows service (your due diligence would be required in order to ensure you're not sending data to a third party) and does what you want it to do. Not sure if it covers your `have to be able to just start the "printer computer"` part, nor how it deals with the client being closed, although it supports webmail services such as Yahoo!, GMail and others, which leads me to "assume" that it's client independent. But I have no personal experience with the program.

Hope it helps somewhat..